# Bind an object in xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to bind a whole object using it's x:Name to a property in another object. For example

```
<local:customImage Tag="{Binding x:Name}"/>
```

How do I go about achieving this?

Update: I tried to implement the suggestions with no luck. The xaml that I'm talking about is as follows:

```
<local:StarBehavior x:Name="starOne" GroupName="myStar"/>
    <local:StarImage BindingContext="{x:Reference starOne}" starTag="{Binding Name}" x:Name="starBlankOne" Source="rating-stars/star_outline.png">
        <local:StarImage.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Star_Tapped"/>
        </local:StarImage.GestureRecognizers>
    </local:StarImage>
</Grid>
```

Perhaps I should try move the starBehaviour into c# as it's not a visual element?

P.S All I'm trying to do is set starTag to an object so if I can do this without binding, I don't mind if there's a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your View has to have the binding context of the object that holds the (public) property "Name"

```
<local:customImage Tag="{Binding Name}"/>
```

EDIT: Try declaring your property like this, it is close to what you did, its just more typesafe (with the nameof(...) operator) and may cover some caveats you didnt write correctly.

```
 public static readonly BindableProperty starTagProperty = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: nameof(starTag),
                                                                                                returnType: typeof(StarBehaviour),
                                                                                                defaultValue: null,
                                                                                                declaringType: typeof(TheClassYouDeclareThisIn),
                                                                                                defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                                                                                propertyChanged: OnStarTagChanged);

        public StarBehaviour starTag
        {
            get { return (StarBehaviour)GetValue(starTagProperty); }
            set { SetValue(starTagProperty, value); }
        }

private static void OnStarTagChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            if (bindable is TheClassYouDeclareThisIn starTagDeclarer && newValue is StarBehaviour newStarTag)
            {
//Does this get called if u change up the starTag property? test it
            }
        }
```

Comment: It didn't work but I amended the original post to include more information

Comment: Ok now i see, the "starTag" might not be a "BindableProperty" hence you cannot bind anything to it. Read up on basic data binding with xamarin, you seem to miss out on things.

Comment: I believe it is. I used to have an error due to it not being a bindable property but I used the following code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace SalApp
{
    public class StarImage : Image
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty starTagProperty = BindableProperty.Create("starTag", typeof(StarBehavior), typeof(StarImage), null);
        public StarBehavior starTag { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: Yes your property starTag seems to miss the SetValue() and GetValue() methods that are needed for the bindable property to function correctly. Check my edit

Answer (score 0):

To bind an object you just have to add the name of the object.
Your property has to be public i.e.

```
public ObjectType Name {get;set;}

<local:customImage Tag="{Binding Name}"/>
```

or if you want to bind your current binding context you have use it like this

```
<local:customImage Tag="{Binding .}"/>
```

also your property "Tag" has to be a bindable property.

Comment: I want to bind the object onto a property that's the thing. So in code, starTag will equal to an object that was set in the xaml

Comment: did you set BindingContext  to your local:StarBehavior ?  or do you want to pass local:StarBehavior control by BindingContext ?

Comment: I want to pass the StarBehavior by context so that starTag = StarBehavior

Answer (score 0):

x: Name references the name of the component being used.
Binding does not relate to the name of the component, it should be this way

for example:

```
<local: customImage x: Name = "NameOfComponent" Tag = "{Binding Name}" />
```